# Full proof of this matrix propierty

Tags: matrices

I have to prove the following question:

?

I asked yesterday and got answers like "Since $A=Y^{-1}XY, A^2=(Y^{-1}XY)(Y^{-1}XY)=Y^{-1}X^2Y$. So $\alpha A^2+\beta A+γI=Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2+\beta X+γI)Y=Y^{-1}\textbf{0}Y=\textbf{0}$." but i didn't understood it at all, could someone please explain this like you would explain it to a kindergardener, BTW this is on a matrices unit so the order of multiplication actually does matter

[image: the math problem]

Comment: Note that matrix multiplication is associative and $YY^{-1}$ is the identity matrix, so $(Y^{-1}XY)^2=Y^{-1}XYY^{-1}XY=Y^{-1}X^2Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke start by substituting:

$$\alpha A^2+\beta A +\gamma I = \alpha(Y^{-1}XY)(Y^{-1}XY)+\beta (Y^{-1}XY) +\gamma I$$

Now you mention that order of multiplication matters. That is true in the sense that matrix multiplication is not [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), however, it is [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). Knowing that we see that

$$\alpha(Y^{-1}XY)(Y^{-1}XY)+\beta (Y^{-1}XY) +\gamma I = \alpha Y^{-1}X(YY^{-1})XY+\beta (Y^{-1}XY) +\gamma I$$

$$=\alpha Y^{-1}X^2Y+\beta (Y^{-1}XY) +\gamma Y^{-1}IY$$

$$=Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2Y+\beta XY +\gamma IY)$$

$$=Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2+\beta X +\gamma I)Y$$

$$=Y^{-1}0Y=0$$